# Advanced Custom Fields - Checkbox values disappears

Tags: wordpress

When I try to add an advanced custom field with checkboxes the values disappear upon saving.

I add a new field, choose the Checkbox option, enter some data (blue : Blue, red : Red etc..) and then hit Update. But when I do, all the data is removed. Other types like Radio button, Select and True / False works perfectly. See the example below:

[image: Checkbox errors]
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnZSG.png)

Any ideas?

ACF version: v3.5.8.1
WP version: 3.5.1

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by downloading the latest version from Github.